# Cannot find the culprit file in my android project even after expanding the main folder

Tags: android, eclipse

The side bar in eclipse shows a red cross on the title of my project folder but there are no such signs in the directories below it in hierarchy. In which particular file does error exist? How can I know that?

Error log shows: Current file is not a match for the given config.

Comment: check your "menifest" file..there may be any error

Comment: even manifest doesn't show any error.. 
i restarted eclipse.. still the error persists..

Comment: import your src files into a brand new project, and make sure you turn on Breadcrumbs in Eclipse as that helps to locate easily `signs`

Comment: i have edited my question.. the error log shows "current file is not a match for the given config." what does that mean..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

formed a new workspace and formed a new project. Added each file individually. Now it shows no error.. but still can't figure out what was wrong with thr previous code..? :=(

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I just came across this now, but I've had the same error too, so I'm sure others have.  There was a quite a bit easier solution than what you had to do, at least in my case.  I had the exact same problem, where my main project said there was an error, so I couldn't debug or run, but there was no apparent error, other than the red X on my main folder.

In order to solve this, I simply closed the project by right-clicking on the main folder, and selected "Close Project".  Then, I right-clicked on the closed project, and selected "Delete".  Don't worry, this will not delete any files, it will only remove it from the workspace, and will make sure you really want to do that by asking you to confirm.  Now, just click on File->Import and select "Existing Projects into Workspace".  Choose your parent folder for your app that was erroring, and import it.  The few times I've had the phantom error on my main app, this has fixed it each time.

Whether there is an underlying cause and this process simply refreshes something in the workspace, I'm not sure, but at this point this fix is fast enough for me to use it.

Hope this helps next time!

Comment: nice.. waiting for the next time.. :P

Comment: haha, hopefully there won't be one for you, but if so, I hope it'll be less of a pain to fix!

Answer (score 1):

Project -> Clean

Answer (score 1):

Closing project and opening it again fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue..

there was a problem in manifest xml..
the path was not set properly. there may be space in the path.. 
I just copied the activity tag from other project and pasted in my project and just edited the path in android:name. it worked fine..